# How to fix relative import error in python without code change?

Tags: python, python-import

In python I have a folder with three files

```
- __init__.py
- module.py
- test_module.py
```

in which the module `module.py` is imported inside the file `test_module.py` as follows:

```
from . import module
```

Of course, when I just run `test_module.py` I get an error

```
> python test_module.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_module.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import module
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

But as I set the `PYTHONPATH` to the absolute path to where I am working in

```
export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`
```

I expect the import to work (as I did set the `PYTHONPATH`). But to my surprise I get the same error!

So can I fix the relative import error **without any code change**?

Comment: I suggest to read the question. I do not want to make any code changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the directory you describe (let's call it `thatdirectory`) is a package, as marked by an `__init__` file, you can "fix" that by `cd`ing a directory higher up, then running

```
python -m thatdirectory.test_module
```

since running modules with `-m` fixes up `sys.path` in a way that makes this particular configuration work.

(In general, any code that messes with `sys.path` manually, or requires changes to `PYTHONPATH` to work, is broken in my eyes...)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but this does not seem to work. I get an error `/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3.8: Error while finding module specification for 'tut_bs.test_module.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: __path__ attribute not found on 'tut_bs.test_module' while trying to find 'tut_bs.test_module.py')`

Comment: Be sure to clear any `PYTHONPATH` changes you may have made. Also, `-m tut_bs.test_module`, no `.py` extension.